# Why does xubuntu require less ram than ubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

Hello i would like to know why Xubuntu requires less ram to work properly than Ubuntu , when both are linux based systems and both are running on linux kernel.
Is it because some of the inbuilt tasks are not running?so the ram isnot flooded by the system?

i have tested both of them on a different types of hardware and the xubuntu was able to run on a way weaker hardware

Comment: Did you test them both?

Comment: yes i did. i am using both of them the documentation also says that the requirements are different

Comment: Yes, do you find the msame in terms of look and feel and usability?

Comment: Xubuntu uses a 2 dimensional desktop whereas Ubuntu provides a 3 dimensional desktop. As you can imagine representing a desktop in 3 dimensions takes more RAM and adds more complexity to the programming. Complexity makes programs larger which also consumes more RAM.

Answer (score 5):

This is not about running Linux kernel. Kernel itself doesn't eat much RAM. It's about usability, features and look and feel they provide and the requirements of default applications they include.

Ubuntu uses compiz to render it's desktop. Compiz is graphically richer than the xfwm4 Xubuntu uses. Compiz provides some very useful gesture support, which xfwm4 doesn't like snapping, hot-corner sensitivity.

Again, all of Xubuntu's default applications cut aesthetics and features to make it less resources hungry. For example, Xubuntu's system monitor doesn't give you a real time graph of CPU, Memory and Net usages.

Another example is, Ubuntu's searching capability. When you search in dash with term *Text Edit*, it will show all text editors, including those applications which neither include **text** nor **edit** in their name. I found Sublime Text, GVim, Medit, Atom including Libreoffice-Writer in the result. Xubuntu features an application finder, when searched didn't show Libreoffice-Writer in the result.

Ubuntu uses Zeitgeist, which works as an activity logger and based on usage pattern of the user, it can correlate applications and items for finding them quickly in future. Xubuntu doesn't include anything like this.

Another example could be the Text Editor they include. Gedit is more feature-rich editor than mousepad. Gedit can be extended using plugins, mousepad can't be extended like this.

The same theory apply to all other applications included in Xubuntu. If anyone use them both, they'll know it obviously.

It's rather surprising from a user who used both to ask this. It's like asking why NFS2 required less RAM than NFS Underground.

Have a look at one of the many videos available featuring Compiz's capability

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4Fbk52Mk1w.

You can find plently of them in Youtube. Watch and you'll admit, you shouldn't expect them with same amount of RAM (and CPU) requirement as of Xubuntu.

Some Reading

- [Xfwm4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce#Xfwm) Wikipedia Article
- [Compiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz) Wikipedia Article
- [Compiz Project Page](http://www.compiz.org/)

Comment: I'm curious. Why would a real time system information graph (an on-demand service, afaik) hinder **basic** and **day-to-day** performance? I don't see the connection other than a guiding principle like "we do everything aesthetically simpler".

Comment: @luchonacho It was 1 example

Answer (score 2):

Xubuntu uses a 2 dimensional desktop whereas Ubuntu provides a 3 dimensional desktop. As you can imagine representing a desktop in 3 dimensions takes more RAM and adds more complexity to the programming. Complexity makes programs larger which also consumes more RAM.

More specifically Xubuntu uses the xfce desktop whereas Ubuntu uses the gnome desktop. The Xubuntu file manager (file browser) is called Thunar. The Ubuntu file manager is nautilus.

For a more detailed comparison check out: [easylinuxtipsproject/xubuntu](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/xubuntu)